# Hide Mobile Number while calling

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to hide the mobile number. In android, is it possible to hide Mobile Number while calling?

Comment: Yes. You need to create your own custom ROM. But main question is what are you trying to achieve by doing it.

Comment: then you have to create your own dialer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is possible to hide Mobile Number while calling?

No , its not possible . You are suppose to violate the user comfort in that case. Call apps which is generally customized of device  manufacturer.